# doOnSuccess on Mono.Void not called

Tags: java, spring-webflux

I am trying to log success statement after process is successful like this:

```
private Mono<Void> sendEvent(EventType eventType, Bundle bundle, String tenantId) {
        EventAbstractFactory<AbstractHealthDataEvent> factory =
            this.eventFactory.getFactory(eventType, bundle, tenantId);
        Optional<AbstractHealthDataEvent> eventOptional = factory.createEvent();

        if (eventOptional.isPresent()) {
            return eventPublisherService.publish(eventType, eventOptional.get())
                .doOnNext(aVoid -> LOGGER.info("{} event published successfully.", eventType.getName()));
        }
        return Mono.empty();
    }
```

When `eventOptional.isPresent()`, then I want to call `.publish` method and then if it is successful, I want to log something in the `LOGGER`. However, this doesn't work. How can I achieve this without changing the return type?

Comment: Don't misuse tags. Your Java stuffs should use the java tag, and the mono tag is for something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logger does not log because you put it in the `doOnNext` method, which is not executed since your `publish` method returns `Mono<Void>` that is empty mono. If you replace `doOnNext` with `doOnSuccess` everything should work as expected.

By the way, you can also simplify your code using `Mono.justOrEmpty` here:

```java
private Mono<Void> sendEvent(EventType eventType, Bundle bundle, String tenantId) {
    EventAbstractFactory<AbstractHealthDataEvent> factory =
        this.eventFactory.getFactory(eventType, bundle, tenantId);

    return Mono.justOrEmpty(factory.createEvent())
        .flatMap(event ->
            eventPublisherService.publish(eventType, event)
                .doOnSuccess(aVoid -> LOGGER.info("{} event published successfully.", eventType.getName()));
        )
}
```